# Retrieving an array of objects in GraphQL & GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create a CMS within my Gatsby website. I am using Markdown to generate all of the projects within my website. Here is an example of what my YAML frontmatter looks like.

```
projectPage:
- Slideshow Banner:
    Link1: 'https://hi.com'
    Link2: 'https://bye.com'
- Images:
    Image1: 'https://hi.com'
    Image2: 'https://bye.com'
```

I am trying to create an array of objects so that I can generate components on a project page and use the object as props for those specific components. In GraphQL, I am unable to just retrieve the array of objects.

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
          path
          projectPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error `must have a selection of subfields`

How can I retrieve just the array of objects?

Comment: projectPage is an object, so GQL needs to know what property to return. Replace `projectPage` with something like `projectPage { imageUrl }`

Comment: Maybe a better question is how can I make it an array of objects? Different components will require different attributes.

Comment: Type of GQL response is defined on the server side, if you need an array of objects, define it appropriately on your backend. At the moment, projectPage example that you posted at the top doesn't describe what properties this object actually has, so it's hard to give you an advice what to put inside of `projectPage { ... }` in your request. What language do you use on the server side?

Comment: As a hacky solution, define projectPage on backend as a string (JSON) and then JSON.parse() it in UI

Comment: @Anonymous I am using GatsbyJS with the `gatsby-transformer-remark` plugin. If you aren't familiar, it takes YAML and converts it into a queryable section for the frontend (which uses React).

Comment: By default, it seems to support only 2 levels of indentation, so if you don't want to put everything on the same line, like `- Images: { Image1: ..., Image2: ... }` or custom format like `- Images: Image1_...__Image2_...` then you probably need to define a type for an object in this array. This article has `html` property for everything that was not defined as a simple property https://danilowoz.com/Advanced-blog-system-in-Gatsby/ and YAML plugin allows to define the type of expected response using a function https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-yaml/#configuration-options

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you for providing your insights. I have found a solution that doesn't require YAML or GraphQL. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/ I am using MarkdownX now in my project.